# Command substitution into pipe

Tags: bash

I have a function

```
function list_all () {
    output=$(sort lastb.txt | tail +2 | head -n -2 | sort | uniq -f3 | tr -s " " | cut -d' ' -f1,3,5,6)
    echo "$output"
}
```

I have a second function

```
function filter_username () {
    read -p "Enter filter: " filter
    output=$(list_all) | grep "^$filter")
    echo "$output"
}
```

Is it possible to assign the `output` variable the output of `list_all` piped into `grep`? So that I don't have to repeat the whole job I made in `list_all`?

Comment: you have an extra right paren in the current code; remove the right paren that follows `list_all`, ie, try changing `$(list_all) | grep "^$filter")` to `$(list_all | grep "^$filter")`; this assumes you have a requirement to store the results in the variable `output` otherwise chepner's answer eliminates the overhead of the variable if all you want to do is display the results on stdout; on the other hand, if the results span multiple lines and you need to process these results later, you may want to look at storing the results in an array, ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`list_all` is a function that writes to standard output; as such, it can be used as the input to `grep` by itself.

```
filter_username() {
    read -p "Enter filter: " filter
    output=$(list_all | grep "^$filter")
    echo "$output"
}
```

Note that you don't need command substitutions in either case if you are only going to immediately write the contents of `output` to standard output and do nothing else with it.

```
list_all () {
    sort lastb.txt | tail +2 | head -n -2 | sort | uniq -f3 | tr -s " " | cut -d' ' -f1,3,5,6
}

filter_username () {
    read -p "Enter filter: " filter
    list_all | grep "^$filter"
}
```